# JQuery Mobile: navigator.app.exitapp() not working on Android devices

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm using PhoneGap framework to develop a mobile application. I would like to add a button exit, using navigator.app.exitapp (), it works fine on my emulator but it is not working on my tablet.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function deconec()
 {
     localStorage.clear(); 
     navigator.app.exitApp();
 }

 </script>

 <a href="" data-role="button" data-icon="home" onclick="deconec()">Quitter</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap might not work with your tablet. I've had problems with using my Kindle Fire HD.  The application would work fine on my phones but not on my Kindle.